# How can I add Confirm and Cancel buttons for Native Base Datepicker

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, datepicker, native-base

I use  component of Native Base and test it on iOS. And I can't show confirm and cancel buttons. For example here "clear" and "done":

[image]

I know about other datepickers, such as:

- [React Native DateTimePicker](https://github.com/react-native-community/datetimepicker)
- [React Native DatePicker by xgfe](https://github.com/xgfe/react-native-datepicker)
- [React Native Date Picker by Henning Hall](https://github.com/henninghall/react-native-date-picker)

But I want to resolve my issue with standart Native Base functionality without extra components added. 
It is possible?